# OCaml Recursive function : sublist elements multiplied by their position in a list and then summed

Tags: ocaml, recursive-query

I’m trying to create a function that takes an int list as an argument and returns the sum of the product between an int and its position in the list. To put in an example this : multSum [5; 11; 15] should return (5 * 1 + 11 * 2 + 15 * 3) = 72.

It should be written recursively and I’m trying while avoiding List.map or List.filter or any other prefabricated functions.

By dividing and reigning the query above, I have so far started by trying the following :

```
let rec tir f acc l =
match l with
|[] -> acc
|h::t -> tir f (f acc h) t ;;
val tir : ('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'a = <fun>
```

then I moved to this :

```
let rec carto f a b =
match (a,b) with
|([],[])->([])
|(h1::t1,h2::t2)->(f h1 h2):: (carto f t1 t2)
|_->invalid_arg "carto";;
val carto : ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> 'a list -> 'b list -> 'c list = <fun>
```

with the final idea to be able to do that :

```
let prod arg1 arg2 =
tir (+) 1 (carto ( * ) arg1 arg2);;
val prod : int list -> int list -> int = <fun>
```

But I am stuck now and I’m not sure of my orientation from here forward. I thought of trying to search for the index in a "l" and replace each index int in the acc, in order to make it work but I'm afraid I'm rather complicating things... Any help please ?

**Edit 1 :**

```
let rec multSum l = 
  let rec indices n xs = match xs with
    | []   -> []
    | h::t -> n::(indices (n+1) t)in

  let rec tir f acc l =
    match l with
    |[] -> acc
    |h::t -> tir f (f acc h) t in

  let rec carto f a b =
    match (a,b) with
    |([],[])->([])
    |(h1::t1,h2::t2)->(f h1 h2):: (carto f t1 t2)
    |_->invalid_arg "carto" in

  let prod arg1 arg2 =
    tir (+) 0 (carto ( * ) arg1 arg2) in

  prod l (indices 1 l);;
val multSum : int list -> int = <fun>
```

Building on your replies, surely these are 'fold' and 'map' rewritten. At least, I'm sure now that I was on the right track. I have come to put together the whole code as signaled above in **Edit 1**.

It seems to be working well... I know that I want a recursive function and here it is. But, do you think it could be done even shorter *recursively of course*?

Comment: I don't see why you wouldn't implement `multSum` directly (maybe with just one auxiliary function), it's quite straightforward. Or you could do `sumList` and `mapi` (map with an extra index argument), that you can reimplement yoourself if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@coredump is quite right about this looking like an ideal scenario for a fold, but the extra functions aren't really that necessary. We can just use a tuple to pass the index and sum information around, then when we're done, discard the index information from the tuple.

```
let sum_list_prod lst =
  let (_, result) = List.fold_left 
    (fun (i, sum) x -> (i + 1, sum + i * x)) 
    (1, 0) 
    lst
  in
  result
```

*Edit:* A simple implementation of a left fold to demonstrate the recursion going on here.

```
let rec foldl f init lst =
  match lst with
  | [] -> init
  | first :: rest -> foldl f (f init first) rest
```

So working through a simple example with `sum_list_prod`:

```
sum_list_prod [2; 3; 4]
```

Calls the fold like so:

```
List.fold_left (fun (i, sum) x -> (i + 1, sum + i * x)) (1, 0) [2; 3; 4]
```

And as that evaluates:

```
List.fold_left (fun (i, sum) x -> (i + 1, sum + i * x)) (1, 0) [2; 3; 4]
List.fold_left (fun (i, sum) x -> (i + 1, sum + i * x)) (2, 2) [3; 4]
List.fold_left (fun (i, sum) x -> (i + 1, sum + i * x)) (3, 8) [4]
List.fold_left (fun (i, sum) x -> (i + 1, sum + i * x)) (4, 20) []
(4, 20)
```

And then we throw away the `4` because we don't need it anymore and are just left with `20`.

Comment: this thing is the proposed is not recursive. I will look into your solution and try to figure if a recursive option of it is feasible. Cheers

Comment: I concede that. I didn't feel it was feasible to comment open @coredump's answer with this suggestion. Hopefully it proves thought-provoking. I will edit to add a recursive implementation of a left fold function so you can see the recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Your `tir` functions looks like a fold; in fact has the exact same type as `List.fold_left`:

```
# List.fold_left;;
- : ('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'a = <fun>
```

In the following snippets the `prod` function looks like a `map2`

```
# List.map2;;
- : ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> 'a list -> 'b list -> 'c list = <fun>
```

You can use a fold and a map to compute the function you want, but you also need first to build a list of indices from the list of values. You could do this as follows:

```
let rec indices n xs = match xs with
  | []   -> []
  | h::t -> n::(indices (n+1) t);;
```

For example:

```
# indices 1 [5;1;3];;
- : int list = [1; 2; 3]
```

<sup>This is not recursive terminal, if you first computed the length of the list, how would you build the list in a recursive terminal way?</sup>

Then you should be able to call `prod` on a list `xs` and on a secondary list `indices 1 xs`. It is a bit wasteful because you need to build an auxiliary list, but it looks quite simple to me to understand, higher-order functions like *map* or *fold* do work on whole lists so there are fewer corner cases to consider.

But, it might be better to first write a direct recursive function for your particular problem before going the more abstract route.

The direct recursive function also requires no additional memory allocation. If you write a recursive terminal function you'll carry additional accumulator values:

- the current position in the list, initially 1
- the current sum of products, initially 0

Then, your function has the following skeleton:

```
let rec f xs index product = match xs with
| []   -> ...
| h::t -> ...
```

You can wrap it in a main function `g`:

```
let g xs = f xs 1 0;;
```

Comment: building on your propositions I have updated my post. In Edit 1 above, I have put the full working code now. Any thoughts maybe ?

Comment: @Nixtwan This is nice, I think you have everything to build the recursive version without Higher-order functions (I am talking about the f function outline here above). Please tell if you have difficulties with that part