# ocaml the sum of elements of list

Tags: list, sum, ocaml

I am a newbie in ocaml and i am stuck on these two exercises

1- first one i have to make the sum of the elements in a list each element mutiplying its own position
for a list l `[4; 7; 3]`

the result should be  `4x1 + 7x2 + 3x3 = 25`

i tried with this code

```
let rec sum l n  =

if l = [] then 0

else (List.hd l) * (List.length l/List.length l) + (sum(List.tl l (n-1 ) * (List.length l - 1)));;
```

but no success

any help would be appreciated

the second exercise

is to calculate the sum of elements of a list in that way

```
`the result would be 7+1 = 8 they are of the same parity`
                    `8-3  = 5 there are not of te same parity`
                    ``
`5-2  = 3 there are not of te same parity`
                    `3 + 3 =6   they are the same parity the last result
```

Any help woulbe be very very appreciated

Thanks all

Comment: It looks like these questions have [very](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68113486/ocaml-recursive-function-sublist-elements-multiplied-by-their-position-in-a-li) [recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68115859/ocaml-recursive-function-dealing-with-parity-between-list-elements-and-an-int) been asked. You may get some insight by reading those answers.

Answer (score 2):

Both exercises are quite similar and require you to go through all the elements of a list while maintaining a state.

For the first, the end result must be maintained as the index that is being browsed. We can use as a state a pair of two integers where the first would be the traversed index and the second the accumulated result, for example `(1, 0)`.

```ml
let sum list = 
  (* We define an internal function hiding the details *)
  let rec aux_sum (i, result) list = 
    match list with
    | [] -> 
       (* If we reach the end of the 
          list, we can returns the result. *)
       result
    | x :: xs -> 
       (* Otherwise, we can accumulate the result and
          processing the tail (`xs`) of the list. *)
       aux_sum (i + 1, result + (x * i)) xs 
  in aux_sum (1, 0) list
```

The second is approximately the same, except that the state to be maintained is much simpler. Indeed, it is not necessary to maintain the index, one can be satisfied to maintain only the current state.

```ml
let other_sum list = 
  (* Like previously, we define an internal function 
     hiding the details *)
  let rec aux_sum result list = 
     match list with 
     | [] -> 
        (* The iteration is done, we can returns 
           the result. *)
         result 
     | x :: xs -> 
        let new_result = 
           if (x mod 2) = (result mod 2) 
           then (* Same parity *) 
             result + x
           else (* Not the same parity *)
             result - y 
        in (* We can loop *)
        aux_sum new_result xs
  in 
  (* Now, we have to get the first element of the list
     in order to deal with *)
     match list with 
     | [] -> 0 
     | x :: xs -> aux_sum x xs
```

The structure of the two functions is broadly similar, the main difference being:

- The type of state maintained
- The logic applied to each iteration
- The definition of the initial value.

#### Additional note

In functional programming, traversing a structure recursively by accumulating a result is a fairly common practice, so to reduce the boilerplate, combinators are generally used. This way of "reducing" a list is called a "fold". In the standard OCaml library, there is a `fold_left` function (https://ocaml.org/api/List.html#VALfold_left) which does exactly what we have just done. For example, we could rewrite our first function as follows:

```ml
let sum list = 
   let (_last_index, result) = 
      List.fold_left 
        (fun (i, result) x -> (i + 1, result + (i * x))) 
        (1, 0) 
        list
   in result
```

Since we have generalized our iteration/accumulation, at the end we have our `(index, result)` pair, but we only want the result, so we only extract the result using pattern matching.

Even though this function is much shorter, it does exactly the same thing as the first one we defined and if you look carefully, you can find the same ingredients (the initial state, the  accumulation logic).

The second example can also be expressed as an `fold`.

Comment: You could simplify even more by writing: `let sum list = List.fold_left (* ... *) (1, 0) list |> snd`. On a side note, I wouldn't advise making complete answers to posts that look like homeworks where not a lof of work has been shown. I used to check SO questions when I asked my students to do some projects and found a lot of my subjects here that I had to flag. Here, OP made a minimal answer to their first question so I guess this one can be answered but the second one is just the question, they provided no answer at all.